# Performance test for graphQL API

Tags: jmeter, performance-testing, graphql

Today I'm doing my API automation testing and performance testing with Jmeter when the server is a REST API.

Now the development changed to graphQL API, and I have two questions about it:

1. What is the best way to perform the automation API and performance testing?
2. Does Jmeter support graphQL API?

Answer (score 6):

I use [Apollo](https://www.apollographql.com/server) to build the GraphQL server, and use JMeter to query the GraphQL API as below.

#### 1. Set up HTTP Request

[image]

#### 2. Set up HTTP Headers

[image]

Depending on your application, you might also need to set up HTTP header Authorization for JWT web tokens, such as:

```
Authorization: Bearer xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
```

#### 3. Set up HTTP Cookie if needed for your app

#### 4. Run the test

[image]

Comment: This allowed me to test our REST API and GraphQL endpoints with the same platform. One thing to remember is to use the \ (backslash) inside the string for double quotes.

Comment: Things to remember 
1. Inside double quotes, if there are any double-quotes replace with (\").
2. The query should be in one line and not multiple lines

Comment: @Yuci, How can we pass varibles that are read from a csv file ?

Answer (score 5):

Disclaimer: I work for LoadImpact; the company behind k6.

If you are willing to consider an alternative, I've recently written a blog post about this topic: [Load testing GraphQL with k6](https://blog.loadimpact.com/load-testing-graphql-with-k6).

This is how a k6 example looks like:

```
let accessToken = "YOUR_GITHUB_ACCESS_TOKEN";

let query = `
 query FindFirstIssue {
   repository(owner:"loadimpact", name:"k6") {
     issues(first:1) {
       edges {
         node {
           id
           number
           title
         }
       }
     }
   }
 }`;

let headers = {
 'Authorization': `Bearer ${accessToken}`,
 "Content-Type": "application/json"
};

let res = http.post("https://api.github.com/graphql",
 JSON.stringify({ query: query }),
 {headers: headers}
);
```

Answer (score 2):

Looking into [Serving over HTTP](http://graphql.org/learn/serving-over-http/) section of the [GraphQL documentation](http://graphql.org/learn/)

> When receiving an HTTP GET request, the GraphQL query should be specified in the "query" query string.

So you can just append your GraphQL query to your request URL.

[image: JMeter Query GraphQL]

With regards to "best practices" - you should follow "normal" recommendations for web applications and HTTP APIs testing, for example check out [REST API Testing - How to Do it Right](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/rest-api-testing-how-to-do-it-right) article.

Answer (score 2):

You can try using [easygraphql-load-tester](https://github.com/EasyGraphQL/easygraphql-load-tester)

#### How it works:

[easygraphql-load-tester](https://github.com/EasyGraphQL/easygraphql-load-tester) is a node library created to make load testing on GraphQL based on the schema; it'll create a bunch of queries, that are going to be the ones used to test your server.

#### Examples:

- [Artillery.io](https://github.com/EasyGraphQL/easygraphql-load-tester/tree/master/examples/artillery)
- [K6](https://github.com/EasyGraphQL/easygraphql-load-tester/tree/master/examples/k6)

#### Result:

Using this package, it was possible to me, to identify a bad implementation using dataloaders on the server.

**Results without dataloaders**

```
All virtual users finished
Summary report @ 10:07:55(-0500) 2018-11-23
  Scenarios launched:  5
  Scenarios completed: 5
  Requests completed:  295
  RPS sent: 36.88
  Request latency:
    min: 1.6
    max: 470.9
    median: 32.9
    p95: 233.2
    p99: 410.8
  Scenario counts:
    GraphQL Query load test: 5 (100%)
  Codes:
    200: 295
```

**Results with dataloaders**

```
All virtual users finished
Summary report @ 10:09:09(-0500) 2018-11-23
  Scenarios launched:  5
  Scenarios completed: 5
  Requests completed:  295
  RPS sent: 65.85
  Request latency:
    min: 1.5
    max: 71.9
    median: 3.3
    p95: 19.4
    p99: 36.2
  Scenario counts:
    GraphQL Query load test: 5 (100%)
  Codes:
    200: 295
```

Answer (score 1):

I am testing our GraphQL Implementation, you will need:

- Thread Group
- HTTP Header Manager: You need to add as `Content-Type: Application/json`
  https://i.stack.imgur.com/syXqK.png
- HTTP Request: use GET and add in the Body Data your query
  https://i.stack.imgur.com/MpxAb.png
- Response Assertion: You want to count as correct requests only responses without errors
  https://i.stack.imgur.com/eXWGs.png
- A Listener:
  https://i.stack.imgur.com/VOVLo.png

Comment: Tried your solution didn't work, please test and then put the solution. 
It is showing error:- 

{"errors":[{"message":"Syntax Error: Unexpected <EOF>","extensions":{"category":"graphql"},"locations":[{"line":1,"column":1}]}]}

Answer (score 1):

I have recently tried API testing with GraphQl with both GET and POST request in Jmeter

Make sure its **POST** request for both **Query and Mutation**

Example Your Graph Ql query

```
{
  storeConfig{
    default_title
    copyright
  }
}
```

For **Jmeter** it would be like this

```
{
    "query":"{ storeConfig { default_title copyright } }"
}
```

**Step up HTTP Request**

[image]

In place of the localhost, your domain name will come. Make sure you don't add **https**

Example:- https://mydomainname.com

In **Jmeter** :- **mydomainname.com**

**Setup HTTP Header Manager**

[image]

For requesting **Mutation** in **Jmeter**

Example mutation in Graphql

```
 mutation {
      generateCustomerToken(
          email: "rd@mailinator.com"
          password: "1234567"
      ) {
          token
   }
}
```

In **Jemeter** mutation will be like this

```
{
    "query":"mutation { generateCustomerToken( email: \"rd@mailinator.com\" password: \"1234567\" ) { token } }"
}
```

Replace **double quotes with (\")** as shown in above query

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way will be to use the GraphQL queries directly in JMeter without the need to convert them to JSON.

All you need to do is to pass "Content-Type" as "application/graphql" in the header.

[Image Link for: HTTP Request with GraphQL Query as input](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NUKoj.png)

[Image Link for: Header details](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H4ZpX.png)